# Is it okay to convert non-ARC Objective-C answers to ARC?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

There are a lot of answers to Cocoa/UIKit (Objective-C in general) answers which are not ARC, so they contain `release` and `retain` calls.

My questions is: Is it okay to edit an answer to use ARC?

ARC is the recommended way to use Objective-C. And it's helpful for people if they want to copy a piece of code and they don't have to convert it to ARC first if they use ARC.

To make clear: I don't suggest doing this, and I haven't converted any code at anytime. I was wondering if this is okay.

Comment: Why was the question down voted?

Comment: Meta.SO uses a different convention. A downvote here just means "I disagree with this". It applies both to questions and answers. As you can see, there are 9 upvotes for Brad's answer. And since people who agree with Brad will disagree with you, it's understandable that your idea got 5 downvotes. Nothing personal, not a fundamentally bad suggestion, but the consensus is against it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No!**  At most you maybe should consider editing in snippets of the equivalent ARC code, clearly identified as edits.  Better would be to just add your own separate answer with the equivalent ARC code (attributing to the original author as appropriate).

If you edit the original code you are putting words in author's mouth and may be inserting a bug in code that is otherwise faultless.

Answer (score 15):

In a year, should we convert all Objective-C code into Swift?

These are perfectly valid answers, and remain so for those not wishing to use automatic reference counting in their projects. Many of the people who left these answers still work in a non-ARC environment, so you'd be imposing a code style on them that may not be their choice.

Frankly, anyone working with ARC-enabled projects is going to have to deal with plenty of non-ARC snippets they find out there beyond Stack Overflow. They're also going to see code snippets that use manually written properties, instead of the @property syntax, or some code with and without dot syntax.

You will be warned by the compiler if you copy and paste this code, and pretty much all you'll need to do is remove the retain and release calls that are highlighted by the compiler. On the other hand, it's far more dangerous for someone copying ARC code into a non-ARC project, because the compiler will accept that just fine and the code will leak memory like a sieve.

No, I don't think it makes sense to go back and edit all of the non-ARC code to make it ARC-compliant, in the same way it won't make sense to go back and re-edit all the Objective-C code in Swift in a year or two. That's on the end user of that code to figure out, and it's one of the reasons I see teachers explaining how to read both kinds of code (and soon, how to read Objective-C as part of their Swift courses).

Comment: Converting Objective-C to Swift is something completely different, these are two completely different languages. But ARC is a new feature in a language. I never said we should go back and edit all answers. I just asked if it is okay to do so and wanted to hear some opinions. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @wumm: "ARC is a new feature in a language" Same thing, you're asking about converting code into a newer version in a way that is very clearly not backwards-compatible.

Comment: As a note (to a mod?) it looks like [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2848393/james-harnett) is going around and suggesting these edits anyways. While [some](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6401968) are properly rejected, [many](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6240365) of them are getting accepted.

Comment: The "should we bilingual-ize older ObjC answers" question has started to come up a bit more. I'm torn here; should we really have people ask new questions to get answers in swift vs editing old correct answers? As an old curmudgeon, I of course think that all Swift devs should comfortably read ObjC (and also C, and maybe some Latin), but is that a long-term answer, and how does SO encourage that (separate answers vs edited-bilingual answers?)

Comment: @RobNapier - Given that we've seen sometimes very different ways of solving the same problems in Swift vs. Objective-C (witness our conversations about error handling), I don't have as much of a problem with separate questions and answers existing for the two languages. As a practical matter, there are so many Objective-C answers (354,035 at a sample query, and that's only the minority that are tagged as such) that it would be infeasible to go back through even a small fraction of these to make them bilingual. In the college programs I advise, they're teaching Swift students how to read ObjC.

Comment: I'll buy that. I hereby declare this the will of "the community." :D